# jQuery Validation for Input Type File

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation on my form with couple of textboxes, drop down lists and a file input. I've also added additional_methods.js for extension method. It works perfectly, except for file input. It shows default error message for required not custom message, and extension part is not working neither.

Html:

```
<input type="file" id="Logo" class="form-input-styled" required>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.form-validate').validate({
    ignore: 'input[type=hidden], .select2-search__field',
    errorClass: 'validation-invalid-label',
    successClass: 'validation-valid-label',
    validClass: 'validation-valid-label',
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
    },
    success: function (label) {
        label.addClass('validation-valid-label').text('Başarılı.');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parents().hasClass('form-check')) {
            error.appendTo(element.parents('.form-check').parent());
        }
        else if (element.parents().hasClass('form-group-feedback') || element.hasClass('select2-hidden-accessible')) {
            error.appendTo(element.parent());
        }
        else if (element.parent().is('.uniform-uploader, .uniform-select') || element.parents().hasClass('input-group')) {
            error.appendTo(element.parent().parent());
        }
        else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
    rules: {
        Logo: {
            required: true,
            extension: "png"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Logo: {
            required: "Please select a business logo!",
            extension: "Please select a valid logo!"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: A `name` attribute is mandatory for the field being validated.   It’s also what you put inside the `rules` object; not Id.  `name=“Logo”`.  This is spelled out in the documentation.

Comment: I am using validator first time, and i missed this. It is possible, right? And, thanks for the downvote. It will remind me to dig deeper before ask any questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! When I add name property to the input, it works perfectly as i wanted. Custom error message is working now.

```
<input type="file" id="Logo" name="Logo" class="form-input-styled" required>
```